# I have two tables giving different outputs. I want to place them side by side on a single page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have two tables giving different outputs. I want to place them side by side on a single page.

Comment: And is there something particular about your code you would like to ask about? Something that doesn't work? Maybe show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Protected Sub SHOWPDF()

```
    Dim Doc As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 0, 0, 15, 5)
    Dim paragraphTable1 As New Paragraph
    Dim mainTable As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(3)
    paragraphTable1.SpacingAfter = 15.0F
    Dim table As New PdfPTable(3)
    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("This is table 1"))
    cell.Colspan = 3
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    table.AddCell(cell)
    table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1")
    table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1")
    table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1")
    mainTable.AddCell(table)

    Dim paragraphTable2 As New Paragraph
    paragraphTable2.SpacingAfter = 10.0F
    Dim table1 As New PdfPTable(3)
    cell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("This is table 2"))
    cell.Colspan = 3
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    table1.AddCell(cell)
    table1.AddCell("Col 1111 Row 1")
    table1.AddCell("Col 2222 Row 1")
    table1.AddCell("Col 3333 Row 1")
    mainTable.AddCell(table1)
    'paragraphTable2.Add(table1)
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, Response.OutputStream)
    writer.GetVerticalPosition(True)
    Doc.Open()

    table.WidthPercentage = 30%
    table.SpacingBefore = 10.0F
    table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    table1.WidthPercentage = 30%
    table1.SpacingBefore = 10.0F
    table1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
    Doc.Add(table)
    Doc.Add(table1)
    Doc.Close()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= pdfff.pdf")
    Response.[End]()
```

the output

Comment: the output is coming horizontally.i want it vertically in a single page.showing both the tables parallely

Answer (score 0):

You can nest tables.  Put the two tables inside a third with two columns, one per column.

You might also be able to use `MultiColumnText`, but I'm not sure.